# How to "apify" OpenLayers with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, leaflet, openlayers, openlayers-3

I was playing with an idea of having a openlayers instance running on node and being able to call it from my website?

For example I would like to send location parameters for it and use openlayers plugins to generate a response (since similar plugin isn't available for Leaflet and I wouldn't like to add two separate mapping librarys on the same page).

Could this be possible with virtualdom or similar?

Comment: What do you mean by "response", exactly?

Comment: For example geojson as return value.

Comment: And what specific OpenLayers plugins are you referring to?